# Remove thumbnail of Qgis from wms,wfs layer

Tags: leaflet, qgis, wms, mapserver

I have created one QGIS map server for serving map as WMS or WFS feature.

As I am adding the layers in QGIS various thumbnails of QGIS is appearing which I do not want to appear in my map. 
Same thing is happening when I am accessing those layers on web via Leaflet. Please help me how to remove these thumbnails.

I am attaching screenshots regarding this problem: [image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201900/remove-thumbnail-of-qgis-from-wms-wfs-layer

Comment: Thanx for your guidance  @IvanSanchez